# 404 error on form submission in Java

Tags: html, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm developing simple web application. I've created Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Mars and I'm using Java 1.8 and Tomcat v8.0.36.
I've created a simple form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Coffee Advice Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action=”SelectCoffee.do”>
Select Coffee characteristics<p>
Color:
<select name=”color” size=”1”>
<option value=”light”> light </option>
<option value=”amber”> amber </option>
<option value=”brown”> brown </option>
<option value=”dark”> dark </option>
</select>
</br></br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

A Servlet:

```
package com.example.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CoffeeSelectionServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside doGet()");
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.println("doGet() is working fine!");

    }

}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>CoffeeAdvice</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <!-- <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> -->
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.web.CoffeeSelectionServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SelectCoffee.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

But when I start Tomcat server and submit this form, I get 404 Error with query string:
http://localhost:8080/CoffeeAdvice/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9DSelectCoffee.do%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9D?%E2%80%9Dcolor%E2%80%9D=%E2%80%9Dlight%E2%80%9D

which is not I intended.
If I make GET request directly from browser bar:

http://localhost:8080/CoffeeAdvice/SelectCoffee.do?color=light

It works absolutely fine!

Please let me know why this query string is generated distorted like this and what I'd have to change.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double quote sign which you are using in form action is not proper

I unescaped your url which is now

"[http://localhost:8080/CoffeeAdvice/Ã](http://localhost:8080/CoffeeAdvice/%C3%83)¢â¬ÂSelectCoffee.doÃ¢â¬Â?âcolorâ=âlightâ"

Fix your double quote.